# Help with a simple BASH script creation

Tags: wireless, bash, scripts, live-usb

## **The problem**

> > *My 16gb LiveUSB session for Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't save certain settings/applications on the persistent section. I must shut down my laptop, thereby erasing everything stored on RAM (I am currently without a hard drive.)*

---

## **The goal**

> > #### To write a script that:
> >
> > > *- Will set power management for wlan0 to OFF
> > >
> > >        - Will await keyboard input from user (as I must then join a wireless network)
> > >
> > >        - Will then accept an input from any key to proceed
> > >
> > >        - Will download and install Adobe Flash
> > >
> > >        - Will download and install Chromium Browser*

*I will, then, transfer this script to the persistent section of my USB dongle.

---

## **The question**

> > Is this even possible and if so, how would I even get started? I have no prior education in coding. However, I grasp the concept. All I'm looking for is a little direction so that I may get started with programming an actual solution to my real-world problem.

***Thanks in advance!

-Andrew***

Answer (score 1):

You can put something like this on your Desktop as `script.sh` and run it with a double-click every time you want to install the software:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
echo "Press any key to continue with Adobe Flash/Chromium installation. "
read -n 1 -s
sudo apt-get -y install flashplugin-installer chromium-browser
exit
```

`iwconfig wlan0 power off` turns off power management. `echo` just prints a line of text. `read -n 1 -s` waits for keyboard input. `apt-get` installs the packages. `exit` closes the terminal session.

Comment: Optionally, omit `exit` if you want the terminal to stay open.